# Remove the duplicated entry from this list

Tags: pandas

Based on the bellow example, how can i remove just the last "A" from the list ? By using duplicates (as i did) it deletes both entries. The end result should be: A, B, C but now i get B,C.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["A", "B", "C", "A"]})
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False,inplace=True) 
print(df)
```

Comment: remove te `keep=False`, `df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True) `

Comment: RIGHT! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set parameter keep="first"